# Как подключить mySQL к Python 3.6?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

Уже насмотрелся разных видео по работе с субд. Но ничего толкового так и не нашёл. Мне нужно подключить именно mySQL. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Зачем видео? В интернете много нормальной *текстовой* документации по использованию библиотек MySQLdb/mysqlclient

Comment: Скачайте [Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/) а дальше: [Connecting to MySQL Using Connector/Python](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html)

Comment: надеюсь ты используешь linux, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-16-04, установка mysql, а здесь уже подробно описывается ка подключиться https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-connecting.html

Answer (score 1):

Я бы использовал [SQL Alchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/features.html) в качестве абстрактной SQL прослойки (proxy) между СУБД и Python.

Пример подключения:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pymysql

db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://mysql_user:mysql_password@mysql_host/mysql_db'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)
```